# php code to select last inserted row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sir, I upload a youtube video src from my cms and need to display video on webpage.
every thing is working fine.

Ehen I upload a data from cms ,every time new row is created in database.but i can not upload youtube video source with every record.

But I need to fetch last uploaded video source from database.

for ex-

In my database there are 5 rows.
Now i need to select last inserted souce from database.
for ex- I need to select row 3  source from database

id          name           source
1           raj            //www.youtube.com/embed/zmotgOJDKXk

2           ravi

3           roy           //www.youtube.com/embed/zmotgOJDKXk

4           martin

5           king

Below is my code to echo and select data

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT id ,source from content order by id desc";
$sub_top=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<?php while ($video= mysql_fetch_array($sub_top)) { ?>

      <div class="video"> <iframe width="292" height="315" src="<?php echo $video['source']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
      <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you saying you need to display last record in descending order only if source present?

Comment: yes. need to display last record in descending order only if source present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE source IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: need to display last record in descending order only if source present

Answer (score 1):

Add the clause "LIMIT 0,1" :

```
$sql = "SELECT id,source FROM content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1 WHERE source <> ''";
```

Comment: only need to display last record in descending order only if source present

Answer (score 1):

don't know what you're asking, but this should find the newest row with a source.

```
$sql="SELECT id ,source from content WHERE source IS NOT NULL order by id desc LIMIT 0,1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to fetch only last record containing youtube URL.

```
select id, source from content where source ilike '%youtube%' order by id desc limit 1
```

this will select one record from db and it has to contain word "youtube".
I don't use mysql so I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **REGEXP** by MySQL in order to conduct this operation. The regular expression should be something like www.youtube.com/(.+)

> SELECT id,source FROM content ORDER BY id WHERE source REGEXP 'www.youtube.com/(.+)'

This will definitely limit it to only show any record with youtube links

Answer (score 0):

To Display last record with source not null:

```
$sql="SELECT id ,source FROM content WHERE source IS NOT NULL ORDER By id desc Limit 0,1";
```

Answer (score 0):

In Frame add Frame unique ids on page and add allowfullscreen=""

Code is below

```
<div class="video">
  <iframe width="292" id="vid_1" height="315" src="<?php echo $video['source']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```